# Some trophoblast excreting digestive enzymes in implantation

Tags: embryology, implantation

I found this paragraph in my study materials about implantation

Original

> Simplest trophoblast excretes trypsin related substances and embedding consists of 3 stages:
>
> 1. The blastocyst (composed of cytotrophoblast and embryoblast) stick to the uterine wall
> 2. Enzymes digest nische (little hole in the endometrium) to the functional layer and the blastocyst deepens in it. The nische is a closed and destroyed functional layer, in it tissue and blood is used for trophic (called a nischtrophic way of feeding)
> 3. Implantation ends in 13½ day when the functional layer covers the blastocyst.
>      Implantation normally takes place in anterior and posterior wall of uterus, sometimes in superior or fundus wall.

My suggestion for corrections

> Syncitiotrophoblast excretes Digestive Enzymes and embedding consists of 3 stages:
>
> 1. The blastocyst (composed of cytotrophoblast and embryoblast) stick to the uterine wall
> 2. Syncytiotrophoblast expresses digestive enzymes which dig a little hole (nische) into endometrium. The hole is usually filled with maternal tissue (so closed) and blood used by the conceptus for histotrophic feeding (nischtrophic way of feeding)
> 3. Implantation should end in 13½ day when the endometrium covers the blastocyst.
>      Implantation normally takes place in anterior and posterior wall of uterus between glands of the hypertrophic endometrium, sometimes in superior or fundus wall.

I cannot accept the phrase **simplest trophoblast** and the use of the words **trypsin related substances**. Really, how can you get trypsin without pancreas? I would not use the word trypsin although the enzymes may have some structural similarities.

**How would you reformulate the paragraph?**

Comment: If you think about what the trophoblast (particularly syncytiotrophoblast) is doing during implantation, then secreting trypsin related substances makes sense.

Comment: @kmm Can you call this trophoblast also simplest trophoblast? Where does the name come from?

Comment: Maybe it's just referring to the undifferentiated trophobast (before cytotriphoblast and syncytiotrophoblast can be identified as such).

Comment: @kmm I made big changes to the paragraph after getting the opinion of another group of students. I tried to fix it so well as I could in the my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what is meant by 'the simplest trophoblast'. I did, however, find this review, pointing to a role of proteases in the implantation process:

> Salamonsen L.A. Salamonsen and Nie, G. (2002) Proteases at the Endometrial–Trophoblast Interface: Their Role in Implantation. Reviews in Endocrine and Metabolic Disorders, 3:133-143

which discusses the roles in implantation of three classes of proteases : matrix metalloproteinases, serine proteinases and cystein proteinases. The reference to 'trypsin-like' presumably relates to the serine proteases. The review reports the results of a number of gene knockout experiments in mice in which genes for individual proteases have been disrupted which indicate that no single enzyme is identified as being essential.

Referring to

> Afonso S et al (1997) The expression and function of cystatin C and cathepsin B and cathepsin L during mouse embryo implantation and placentation. Development 124:3415-3425.

the authors of the review state that:

> [they] demonstrated that cysteine proteases play a critical role in implantation. Cathepsin B mRNA was expressed by mouse trophoblast throughout the invasive period (days 5.5±10.5) while the proteins for cathepsins B and L were localized to the mature invasive trophoblast giant cells; activity of these enzymes was also demonstrated. Cathepsin L was also present within the stroma particularly in the lateral decidualizing zone. Cystatin C, the major inhibitor of cathepsins, was shown to be a major product of the adjacent decidualizing stroma close to the embryo, suggesting a restraining role. After the completion of placental trophoblast invasion (day 11.5) the trophoblast cells express high levels of cystatin C, probably in association with a switch from an invasive cell type to one providing nutrients to the conceptus [35]. In addition, treatment of pregnant mice with E-64, a synthetic cysteine protease inhibitor, resulted in failure of implantation and normal uterine decidualization.

Comment: You are completely right. I think the simplest trophoblast is mistake and the original author meant syncytiotrophoblast. Those enzymes secreted are structurally trypsin related. However, I would never call them such only. The best way to start would be to say digestive enzymes such as trypsinase digging a hole into the endometrium.

Comment: Perona and Wassarman (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3514318) showed that a 'trypsin-like proteinase' (strypsin) is required to hatch the blastocyst and that it is concentrated on the wall-side cells of the blastocyst.